# File grep for specific column

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

How to search each line in first file against a specific column in a second comma separated file so that whole line in the first file matches the whole column in the second file.

`grep -Ff file1 file2`, will search the entire line in the second file, but i want to search on a specific column.

Eg.

*file1.txt*

```
20
300
```

*file2.txt*

```
200,10
220,2
300,5
```

I want the result to only match 300,5 and not the first 2 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file{1,2}
```

there are many answers already on this site with explanation of how this works, please refer to them.